# I can`t print the result, float object not callable

Tags: python, math

The user needs to type the variables "x", "y" and "z" and the code has to solve the math problem "factor" but I am getting the error "float object not callable"... Please help! PYTHON

```
x = float(input("INSERTE X: "))
y = float(input("INSERTE Y: "))
z = float(input("INSERTE Z: "))
factor = float(((((x^z)/y)+(z^2))**2)-((x+y)^2))
print(factor)
```

Comment: did you define `float` before? print `type(float)`

Comment: Which line is in error?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't generate that error (it does have a different error). The problem must be in code you haven't shown. As suggested, you likely reassigned `float`.

Comment: The code as written will not produce that error, so there is something you are not including. Please create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4):

Exponentiation in Python works like this: `x**z` and not like `x^z`. Try changing that in your code.

Comment: ...which is the next problem OP will hit once this one is fixed. I think this should be a comment since it doesn't solve the stated problem.

Comment: Worked for me. As long as the numbers are all positive/small.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the same error message as you. "float object not callable", means that you wrote something like `x()`, or `2.0()`, which is wrong syntax. Also, Notice that you are using both `^` and `**` to represent power. In python, `^` stands for `bitwise-XOR`, not power.